# Trying to create simple chat app with node js - cant host from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, localhost, chat

I and my sister went to do 90 days challenge.

I am asking her to draw me something (she is a graphic designer learning to create some paintings with an iPad and I am learning to code). This is the way how we would like to motivate ourselves to improve our skills. :) maybe this will inspire someone..

The challenge for me was to do a simple chat app so we could change a few text messages - that's all.

I did some research, downloaded node.js (never used before), downloaded socket.io, and build something with help of tutorials from the internet.

When I am running this app locally its works fine - I can send messages from browser to browser.

I've tried to used xampp to host it so we could type something to each other but it doesn't work - that's the goal.

I've added IIS rules(if it's a matter), I made changes to the firewall added exceptions to open port 3000 but it still does not work.

I am receiving error 400 or io is not defined.

I think its outgrown my skills - I am too newbie, but I would like to do anything to pass this challenge.

Please check the below code. I would appreciate any advice or clue which would help to solve the issue.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- font awesome link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script defer src="./script.js"></script>
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="chatWindow">
    </section>
    <form id="sendMessage">
        <input type="text" id="messageText">
        <button type="submit" id="sendMessageBtn"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js code:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);

const users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('new-user', name => {
        users[socket.id] = name;
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', name);
    })

    socket.on

    socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', {
            message: message,
            name: users[socket.id]
        });
        console.log(message);
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id]);
        delete users[socket.id];

    })

})
```

script.js code:

````
const messageForm = document.getElementById('sendMessage');
const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chatWindow');
const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageText');

const name = prompt("Nickname:");
addMessage(`${name} Welcome!`);
socket.emit('new-user', name);

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
    addMessage(`${data.name} : ${data.message}`);
});

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
    addMessage(`${name} you have joined`);
});

socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
    addMessage(`${name} user disconnected form the server`);
});

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const message = messageInput.value;
    addMessage(`Ty : ${message}`);
    socket.emit('send-chat-message', message);
    messageInput.value = '';
});

function addMessage(message) {
    const chatMessage = document.createElement('div');
    const addUserName = document.createElement('h3');
    chatMessage.classList.add("message");
    chatMessage.innerText = message;
    chatWindow.append(chatMessage);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is failing to load the socket.io library.
`localhost` is only working on your local pc
so change the below in your `html` code

> ```
> <script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
> ```

to

> ```
> <script defer src="http://**your_ip_address**:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
> ```

if you wanna check your IP address, you can check in here.
https://www.google.com/search?q=get+my+ip

Comment: ok. if you use in windows 
run - cmd - ipconfig /all and tell me ipv4 address first 3 numbers.

Comment: If your ip starts with 192.~~~
that change to that ip address and test in same wifi.

Comment: i followed this guide: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

It fixed my issues. anyway Many thanks for support <3